# fineUploader deleting a file

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I use Fine Uploader Version: 5.0.8

1) I choose file 1.png

2) PHP script renames and upload with a new name fdba4551.png

3) I want to delete the file but not know how to pass parameters `unlink($UploadDir.$_POST['??????????']);`

I can not delete the file fdba4551.png

my PHP

```
if($method == 'POST')
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($TempName, $PatchNewFile))//$PatchNewFile = uploads/fdba4551.png
    {
        $return = array('success'=>true,'uuid'=>$uuid,'uploadName'=>$NewFile);//$NewFile = fdba4551.png
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
}
elseif($method == 'DELETE')
{
    unlink($UploadDir.$_POST['??????????']);//?????????????
}
```

my java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#upl').fineUploader({
        debug:true,

        deleteFile:{
            enabled:true,method:'POST',endpoint:'upload/'
        },
        request:{
            endpoint:'upload/'
        },
        callbacks:{
            onComplete:function(id, name, response)
            {
                $('#file').append('<input type="hidden" name="load_file[]" value="'+response.uploadName+'" id="'+id+'">');
            },
            onDelete:function(id)
            {
                $('#file #'+id).remove();
            }
        },
        validation:{allowedExtensions:['jpeg','jpg','png','gif'],acceptFiles:'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',itemLimit:10,sizeLimit:5*1024*1024}
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [delete file endpoint handler section of the docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html#deleting-files):

1. Handle the POST or DELETE at your specified endpoint
2. Locate the file based on the file UUID included in the path of the request.
3. Delete the file.